# Mobile Native Dynamic Maps vs Dynamic Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In google document:

**Mobile Native Dynamic Maps:**

User interactions with the map, such as panning, zooming, or switching map layers, do not generate additional map loads.

**Dynamic Maps:**

User interactions with the map, such as panning, zooming, or switching map layers, do not generate additional map loads.

***But My Questions about Mobile Native Dynamic Maps:***

1)**Can I show 1K or 2K marker?**

2)**Can my marker have pop-up?**

3)**Can I use double-click Listener and click Listener?**

4)**Can i draw Line and Circle ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer your questions based off of the Maps SDK for Android, but the same applies to the iOS SDK and the web-based JavaScript API.

1) To show a large number of markers you can use [marker clustering](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/utility/marker-clustering).

2) Yes, see [info windows](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/infowindows).

3) You can listen to click [events](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/events) on e.g. map, marker, info window.

4) Yes, polylines and circles are [supported](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/shapes).

Hope this clarifies your doubts.

Comment: my question was for Mobile Native Dynamic Maps

Comment: Right, Mobile Native Dynamic Maps includes both the Android and the IOS SDKs. :)